# nodejs app throwing unexpected token on typescript files in dependences

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, unexpected-token

I have a nodejs app in which I am introducing TypeORM for the repository layer.
I have been struggling for several days now with unexpected token errors in node_modules dependencies.

To track down the root cause I have created a very simple application, based on the sample application described in the TypeORM documentation. I added dotenv as a dependency and a very simple environment file and I am indeed getting the error in .../dotenv/types/test.ts at the moment I'm trying to connect to the DB using TypeORM. I have no clue why the application is trying to parse that file.

I tried running the application using ts-node as well as compiling the code with tsc and running the app directly. Same result.
I also tried several targets in tsconfig.json and tried running the project with esm. No luck so far.

I must be doing something wrong and I hope someone here can point out what that is. I added the basic application that throws the error in a [github repo](https://github.com/quintmouthaan/testtypeorm)

Here is the error:

```
/Users/quintmouthaan/projects/weareeves/eves-api/node_modules/dotenv/types/test.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { config, parse } from "dotenv";
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/quintmouthaan/projects/prj/api/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:384:14)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
```

And here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "allowJs": true
   }
}
```

and the ormconfig.json file:

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "postgres",
   "password": "",
   "database": "db",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": false,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

and finally the package.json file:

```
{
   "name": "TestTypeORM",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
   "devDependencies": {
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "typescript": "3.3.3333"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
      "pg": "^7.3.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "typeorm": "0.2.20"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
   }
}
```

Comment: i've checked your repo and it works well, doesn't throw any error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It was indeed a silly mistake.

I set the env variable TYPEORM_ENTITIES=**/*.ts
Because of this TypeORM was looking for entities in all foders, including node_modules and that caused the errors while connecting.

I spent way too much time on this, so I hope this at least helps someone else in the future :-).